# SQL Query to Convert 2019/05/21 00:00:00 format to 21-JUN-19(i.e., DD-MON-YY)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date format "2019/05/21 00:00:00" and I need to convert this into "21-JUN-19" using SQL. How can I convert this?

Comment: I'm rather confused.  Are you starting with a string or a date?  Do you want to convert the value to a string or a date?

Comment: Or do you just want to change how your client displays a date - either for this specific date [column] or all dates? If you explain your wider scenario it might reveal that you're misunderstanding how Oracle dates work (which is quite common!) and what you really need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr()` and `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(substr('2019/05/21 00:00:00', 1, 10), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the source value is a string, then

- first convert it to a date (using `to_date`, with appropriate format mask)
- then convert it to a string (using `to_char`, again with appropriate format mask)

By the way, why are you converting 2019/**05**/21 into **jun**? It can be done, no problem (`ADD_MONTHS` does that), just wondering whether you did it intentionally or by mistake.

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('2019/05/21 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mon-yy') result from dual;

RESULT
---------
21-may-19

SQL>
```